# Adding a column thats result of difference in consecutive rows in pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

Lets say I have a dataframe like this

```
    A   B
0   a   b
1   c   d
2   e   f 
3   g   h
```

0,1,2,3 are times, a, c, e, g is one time series and b, d, f, h is another time series.
I need to be able to add two columns to the orignal dataframe which is got by computing the differences of consecutive rows for certain columns.

So i need something like this

```
    A   B   dA
0   a   b  (a-c)
1   c   d  (c-e)
2   e   f  (e-g)
3   g   h   Nan
```

I saw something called diff on the dataframe/series but that does it slightly differently as in first element will become Nan.

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Use [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html).

```
df['dA'] = df['A'] - df['A'].shift(-1)
```

Comment: what if 'A' contains list elements?

Comment: It works as long as that operation makes sense for whatever values are in your dataframe! For example, if each "cell" in your DataFrame is a list, you can do `df['A'] + df['A'].shift()`, but you can't subtract since subtraction isn't defined for lists.

Comment: What can you do about the 'NaN' in the first/last row?

Comment: @AndréFernandes what would you like to be there? You can always do a `fillna` afterwards, but if you're shifting down, what would be a sensible value for the first row?

Comment: For example, hourly differences of an cumulative counter. The first row has to be filled with something, either 0 or the value from another of the row's fields.

Comment: Okay just use `fillna` on the result then. Eg `df['dA'].fillna(0)`

Comment: i am getting SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead

Comment: @PaariVendhan That's a very common issue with pandas, and has to do with how you've defined your dataframe elsewhere. It's not related to the `shift` method. Here's a very long article https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/ and a shorter stackoverflow answer that may be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625582/how-to-deal-with-settingwithcopywarning-in-pandas

Comment: Why not just `df['dA'] = df['A'] - df['B']` ? Any benefit of using this expression?

Comment: @outsider you may want to re-read the question. Column `dA` does not depend on column `B`.

Answer (score 51):

You could use `diff` and pass `-1` as the `periods` argument:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [9, 4, 2, 1], "B": [12, 7, 5, 4]})
>>> df["dA"] = df["A"].diff(-1)
>>> df
   A   B  dA
0  9  12   5
1  4   7   2
2  2   5   1
3  1   4 NaN

[4 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: how can I manage the same problem when 'A' has list elements only instead of scalar ?

Comment: @LeoCella You can manage them by not allowing them to be in a list.

Comment: The accepted answer is interesting, but I think this is the better answer

Answer (score 3):

When using data in CSV, this would work perfectly:

```
my_data = pd.read_csv('sale_data.csv')
df = pd.DataFrame(my_data)
df['New_column'] = df['target_column'].diff(1)
print(df) #for the console but not necessary
```

Answer (score 1):

Rolling differences can also be calculated this way:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(my_data)
my_data = pd.read_csv('sales_data.csv')
i=0
j=1
while j < len(df['Target_column']):
    j=df['Target_column'][i+1] - df['Target_column'][i] #the difference btwn two values in a column.
    i+=1 #move to the next value in the column.
    j+=1 #next value in the new column.
    print(j)
```

Comment: this is when you want to calculate the rolling differences in a column in CSV, for example, you want to get the difference between two consecutive values in a column (Target_column) and store the value in a different column(New_column). Rolling differences for example, you have a column called ['Profit'], to get the differences to use in calculating marginal revenue, you will do value2 - value1, value3- Value2, Value 4 - Value 3.... etc