# How to distribute column values to another columns based on condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a small dataframe. An example is given below.

```
+-------+---------+---------+------+----------+  
| code  | surplus | deficit | gone | has come |  
+-------+---------+---------+------+----------+
| 0100  |    1000 |       0 |      |          |
| 0103  |       0 |     100 |      |          |
| 0104  |       0 |     600 |      |          |
| 0190  |       0 |       0 |      |          |
| 0191  |       0 |     800 |      |          |
| 0192  |     500 |       0 |      |          |
| 0193  |     700 |       0 |      |          |
| 0194  |       0 |     300 |      |          |
| 0195  |       0 |       0 |      |          |
+-------+---------+---------+------+----------+
```

I need to distribute the data from the column `surplus` so as to cover the data in the column `deficit`. In the column `gone` write down how much I took from the column `surplus`, and in the column `has come` write down how much I added to fill the deficit. From the column `surplus` I take the data as the values decrease. And always start with the largest deficit.

In my example it will look like this:

To cover the biggest deficit (In the example this is `800`) i take part of value `1000`.

To cover the next deficit (In the example this is `600`) i take the remainder of the value `1000` and I take `400` from the value `700`.

To cover the deficit  `300` i take the remainder of the value `700`.

And, finally, to cover the deficit  `100` i take part of value `500`.

The result should be the next dataframe:

```
+------+---------+---------+------+----------+
| code | surplus | deficit | gone | has come |
+------+---------+---------+------+----------+
| 0100 |    1000 |       0 | 1000 |        0 |
| 0103 |       0 |     100 |    0 |      100 |
| 0104 |       0 |     600 |    0 |      600 |
| 0190 |       0 |       0 |    0 |        0 |
| 0191 |       0 |     800 |    0 |      800 |
| 0192 |     500 |       0 |  100 |        0 |
| 0193 |     700 |       0 |  700 |        0 |
| 0194 |       0 |     300 |    0 |      300 |
| 0195 |       0 |       0 |    0 |        0 |
+------+---------+---------+------+----------+
```

The values in the columns `surplus` and `deficit` can be different.

I can't come up an algorithm for this task. I would be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: So basically you start by adding up all the surpluses? Then you cover as much of the deficits as you can from the total surplus?

Comment: @ArthurTacca In general, this is so, but I need to start with the largest value in the column `surplus`, and then take the rest in descending order (I mean `1000`, `700`, `500`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid I don't know pandas so I can't give the detail of the answer, but here is a general alogrithm that I think would work fine. It's up to you to match this against pandas API.

For the "has come" column:

- Sort the entries by deficit (descending)
- Calculate the cumulative sum of deficit entries in this sorted list
- Bound this by sum(surplus) i.e. create a column `max(cumsum(deficit), sum(surplus))`
- Now do the difference of each item with the next one (I think this is the pandas.Series.diff method?), using 0 as the "-1"th entry (maybe you'll have to add a dummy row?). This is your "has come" value

For the "has come" column (if `sum(surplus) >= sum(deficit)`):

- In this case you just set "has come" = "deficit" for all rows, which will be faster than the above computation
- But if you don't check for this case explicitly, the above calculation will still work

For the "gone" column: Just do exactly the same stuff as above, reversing "deficit" and "surplus".

Edit: In your example the gone column is the tricky one, because in that case sum(deficit) < sum(surplus). Here's the above procedure on surplus.

```
sum(surplus) = 2200
sum(deficit) = 1800

+------+---------+---------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+----------------+
| code | surplus | deficit | cumsum(surplus) | max(cumsum(surplus),sum(deficit)) | diff(prev row) |
+------+---------+---------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+----------------+
| NaN  |       0 |       0 |               0 |                                 0 |           NaN  |
| 0100 |    1000 |       0 |            1000 |                              1000 |           1000 |
| 0193 |     700 |       0 |            1700 |                              1700 |           700  |
| 0192 |     500 |       0 |            2200 |                              1800 |           100  |
| 0191 |       0 |     800 |            2200 |                              1800 |           0    |
| 0103 |       0 |     100 |            2200 |                              1800 |           0    |
| 0104 |       0 |     600 |            2200 |                              1800 |           0    |
| 0190 |       0 |       0 |            2200 |                              1800 |           0    |
| 0194 |       0 |     300 |            2200 |                              1800 |           0    |
| 0195 |       0 |       0 |            2200 |                              1800 |           0    |
+------+---------+---------+-----------------+-----------------------------------+----------------+
```

The final column is the result you want. Note that I added a dummy row to the start so that I could calculate pairwise differences. It turns out the `shift()` is the key method you need for calculating that column; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142967/adding-a-column-thats-result-of-difference-in-consecutive-rows-in-pandas)

Edit 2: I thought it might be worth adding an alternative solution. It's a bit harder to understand, but it might be a bit easier to implement because you don't need to fiddle with an extra dummy row.

- As before: Sort the entries by deficit (descending)
- As before: Calculate the cumulative sum of deficit entries in this sorted list
- New: Find the index of the first row where the cumulative sum is greater than the sum of the surplus (I don't how easy it is to get this in pandas). Let's call this `i` (with `i=Inf` if no such row exists).
- For all rows before this index (i.e. `df[:i]`), set "has come" = "deficit"
- For all rows after this index (i.e. `df[i+1:]`), set "has come" = 0
- For that row (i.e. `df[i]`, if `i` exists), set "has come" to:

  - `has come = sum(surplus) - (cumsum(deficit) - deficit)`
  - (BTW, `(cumsum(deficit) - deficit)` is actually equal to cumsum(deficit) of the previous row, or 0 if this is the first row.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Could you please explain in more detail what I need to do in the fourth step for the  "has come"  column? I'm afraid I did not fully understand.

Comment: @YanaDolyuk I added some detail

Comment: An elegant solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: BTW I added another method (really just a variation of the other one). Don't know if it's any easier.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to write code for this method.

Answer (score 0):

For the question "How to distribute column values to another columns based on condition in pandas?" maybe the function  *np.where*  is what you are looking for:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

# df[Column title] = np.where ( condition on this line, if condition true then value to assign, else value to assign)
df["gone"] = np.where((df["surplus"] - df["deficit"]) > 0 , df["surplus"] - df["deficit"] , 0)
df["has come"] = np.where((df["surplus"] - df["deficit"]) < 0 , 0, df["deficit"] - df["surplus"] )
```

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired results when I test the code.  I think the question is more complicated than it appears at first glance.  Look at row where code=0192

Comment: Yes I know, this is just an idea to answer to the title, not the question.

Comment: OK, just checking, as the question is not super clear.  I did not downvote btw.  I don't think this is a complete answer but not deserving of a downvote either.