# subtract previous column from current column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sklearn-pandas

I have two columns, column A and column B. From the 2nd rows to the last I want to subtract previous row of column B with current row of column A and store in Column B only. How can I achieve this?
I tried by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142967/adding-a-column-thats-result-of-difference-in-consecutive-rows-in-pandas) but its still not working. Please help

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can achieve it:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(1,20,5),
                  'B':np.random.randint(1,20,5)})
```

[image]

```
df['B'] = df.A - df.B.shift(1)
```

Output:

[image]