# Finding difference between two columns of a dataframe along with groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I saw a primitive version of this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23142967/adding-a-column-thats-result-of-difference-in-consecutive-rows-in-pandas)

but i my dataframe has diffrent names and i want to calculate separately for them

```
   A   B   C
0  a   3   5
1  a   6   9
2  b   3   8
3  b  11  19
```

i want to groupby A and then find diffence between alternate B and C.something like this

```
   A   B   C   dA
0  a   3   5   6
1  a   6   9  NaN
2  b   3   8  16
3  b  11  19  NaN
```

i tried doing

```
df['dA']=df.groupby('A')(['C']-['B'])
df['dA']=df.groupby('A')['C']-df.groupby('A')['B']
```

none of them helped
what mistake am i making?

Comment: how are the values of dA calculated in your example? Where are 6 and 16 coming from?

Comment: 9 from C - 3 from B for a ,similarly 19 from C - 3 from B for b

Comment: If i just do df['dA']=df['C']-df['B'],it works but dA also contains 2(between 6 and 16) Which is calculated using one data from a and one from b. Which i dont want so i want to use it with groupby

Comment: are you looking for `df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x['C'].shift(-1) - x['B'])`?

Comment: Yes,thank u @Ben.T

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, here is one way to perform the calculation:

```
# create the data frame
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''idx    A   B   C
0  a   3   5
1  a   6   9
2  b   3   8
3  b  11  19
'''

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+', engine='python').set_index('idx')
```

Now, compute `dA`.  I look last value of C less first value of B, as grouped by A.  (Is this right?  Or is it max(C) less min(B)?). If you're guaranteed to have the A values in pairs, then @BenT's `shift()` would be more concise.

```
dA = (
    (df.groupby('A')['C'].transform('last') - 
     df.groupby('A')['B'].transform('first'))
       .drop_duplicates()
       .rename('dA'))

print(pd.concat([df, dA], axis=1))

     A   B   C    dA
idx                 
0    a   3   5   6.0
1    a   6   9   NaN
2    b   3   8  16.0
3    b  11  19   NaN
```

I used `groupby().transform()` to preserve index values, to support the `concat` operation.